# Distribution of energy in an electric and magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Are the energy of the electric field and the energy of the magnetic field concentrated on their sources OR are they scattered in the environment where the fields arent zero? What is the formula that supports your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy density of an electrostatic field is given by,

$$\rho =\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon |\mathbf{E}|^2$$

where $\varepsilon$ is the permittivity of the medium. Hence, the total energy stored in a particular volume $V$ is given by a volume integral of the density, i.e.

$$U = \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon\int_{V}\mathrm{d}^3 x \, |\mathbf{E}|^2$$

If all the energy were localized at a particular point in the field, such as near the center, then at some point as we expand the volume $V$, we would arrive at a point where $U$ would be constant, but this is not the case. The energy is in fact present throughout the entire electric field.

Furthermore, the *reach* of the electric field is infinite; notice that the electric field strength due to a charge,

$$\frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon r^2}$$

never vanishes, regardless of the size of $r$ (except at $r=\infty$). Another charge in the field will always have some electric potential energy.

Comment: How about the magnetic field?

Comment: @user3543012: Basically, the same argument applies for $\mathbf{B}$.